# Why isn't my button showing when I call the jQuery show method on it after it has been hidden?

Tags: jquery

I have 3 buttons on my page that generate a different sized grid depending on which one you press. When they do this, however, I get them off the screen by calling `$('.button').hide();`. When the user clicks on text `<p onclick="diffReset()">Click to change Difficulty</p>`, then the `onclick` should run the following function:

```
var diffReset = function() {
   $('.grid-box').hide();
   $('.button').show();
};
```

This hides the grid box, but the buttons don't show up. Does anyone know why it's not working?

Here is my full code:

```js
var $bcdef = "";
var $mines = [];

var chooseMines = function(num) {
  var temp, bool, numbers = [];
  for (i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
    do {
      bool = 0;
      temp = Math.floor(100 * Math.random()) + 1;
      for (j = 0; j < numbers.length; j++) {
        if (numbers[j] === temp) {
          bool = 1;
        }
      }
    } while (bool)
    numbers.push(temp);
  }
  while (bool);
  $mines = numbers;
};

var setupGrid = function(num) {
  var mine, c = 0,
    $tablestr = "<table class='grid'>";
  chooseMines(num);
  $('.button').hide();
  $('.button').show();
  for (var i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
    $tablestr += "<tr id='r" + i.toString() + "'>";
    for (var j = 1; j <= num; j++) {
      mine = 0;
      for (var k = 0; k < $mines.length; k++) {
        if (j * i === $mines[k]) {
          mine = 1;
        }
      }
      if (mine) {
        $tablestr += "<td id='b" + (j * i).toString() + "' class='mine'";
      } else {
        $tablestr += "<td id='b" + (j * i).toString() + "'>";
      }
      $tablestr += "<div class='img-box'>" + (j + (num * (i - 1))).toString() + "</div>";
      $tablestr += "</td>";
    }
    $tablestr += "</tr>";
  }
  $tablestr += "</table>";
  $('span').append($tablestr);
};

var diffReset = function() {
  $('.grid-box').hide();
  $('.button').fadeIn(200);
};

var buttonControl = function() {
  $('.button').mouseenter(function() {
    $bcdef = $(this).css('border-color');
    $(this).css('border-color', 'blue');
    $(this).css('color', 'red');
  });
  $('.button').mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).css('border-color', $bcdef);
    $(this).css('color', 'black');
  });
  $('.button').click(function() {
    var $id = $(this).attr('id');
    if ($id === "fifteen") {
      setupGrid(15);
    } else if ($id === "eight") {
      setupGrid(8);
    } else if ($id === "ten") {
      setupGrid(10);
    }
  });
};

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on('mouseenter', 'table tr td div', function() {
    $(this).css('border-color', 'black');
  });

  $(document).on('mouseleave', 'table tr td div', function() {
    $(this).css('border-color', '#cccccc');
  });
});

$(document).ready(buttonControl);
```

```css
.header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 20%;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #efefef;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #80ffff;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Comic Sans MS", cursive;
}
.sub-header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 10%;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #efefef;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #e5ffff;
}
.img-box {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: radial-gradient(#cccccc 20%, #999999 80%);
  border: 2px solid #cccccc;
  border-radius: 2px;
  align-content: center
}
.img-box img {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.button {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #efefef;
  height: 30px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 2px #999999 solid;
  border-radius: 8px;
  font-family: "Modern No. 20";
  font-weight: bold;
  top: 200px;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
}
.button p::selection {
  background: #f2f2f2;
}
.button p {
  position: relative;
  top: -8px;
}
#smile {
  content: url("http://findicons.com/files/icons/1995/web_application/48/smiley.png");
}
#flag {
  content: url("http://r34.imgfast.net/users/3416/14/05/34/smiles/1205344956.png");
}
table {
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: white;
}
.mine {
  background: red;
}
.header p {
  text-shadow: 2px 2px gray;
  right: 1px;
}
.sub-header {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 0px;
}
.body {
  background: #d9d9d9;
  height: 1000px;
  width: 2000px;;
}
#ten {
  left: 500px;
  bottom: 100px;
  width: 120px;
}
#fifteen {
  left: 900px;
  bottom: 200px;
}
.grid-box {} .grid {
  margin: auto;
}
.grid * {
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}
.body > p {
  float: right;
  color: blue;
  text-decoration: underline;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
-->
<html>

<head>
  <title>Minesweeper Web App</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="header">
    <h1>Minesweeper!!!!</h1>
    <p>Made by Desmond</p>
  </div>
  <div class="sub-header">
    <div class="img-box" id="left">
      <img src="#" id="smile" alt="this game is broken!" />
    </div>
    <div class="img-box" id="right">
      <img src="#" id="flag" alt="This game is broken!" />
    </div>
    <p id="score">Score:</p>
  </div>
  <div class="body">
    <p onclick='diffReset()'>Click to change difficulty</p>
    <div class="grid-box">
      <span></span>
      <div class="button" id="eight">
        <p>Easy (8x8)</p>
      </div>
      <div class="button" id="ten">
        <p>Medium (10x10)</p>
      </div>
      <div class="button" id="fifteen">
        <p>Hard (15x15)</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I would guess it's because your buttons are within the div that you hid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please remove the buttons from div which you are hiding try this code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
-->
<html>

<head>
  <title>Minesweeper Web App</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="header">
    <h1>Minesweeper!!!!</h1>
    <p>Made by Desmond</p>
  </div>
  <div class="sub-header">
    <div class="img-box" id="left">
      <img src="#" id="smile" alt="this game is broken!" />
    </div>
    <div class="img-box" id="right">
      <img src="#" id="flag" alt="This game is broken!" />
    </div>
    <p id="score">Score:</p>
  </div>
  <div class="body">
    <p onclick='diffReset()'>Click to change difficulty</p>
    <div class="grid-box">
      <span></span>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div class="button" id="eight">
        <p>Easy (8x8)</p>
      </div>
      <div class="button" id="ten">
        <p>Medium (10x10)</p>
      </div>
      <div class="button" id="fifteen">
        <p>Hard (15x15)</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you. For some reason I thought I had given the dynamically added table the class `.grid-box` versus giving the div tag that class.